# C++ захват переменной из лямбда функции

Tags: c++, lambda

есть такая функция, которая принимает другую функцию:

```
GLvoid Graphics::SceneGraph::Node::childrenForEach(GLvoid(*callback)(Node* child)) noexcept
{
    Node* iterator = mChild;
    while (iterator) 
    {
        callback(iterator);
        iterator = iterator->mNextNode;
    }
}
```

Хочу вызвать ее следующим образом:

```
Tools::ShaderProgram& shader = mShaderManager.getShader(BASE_SHADER);
shader.use();

if (mRootNode->isExistChildren()) 
{
    mRootNode->childrenForEach([&shader](Node* child)
    {
        if (child->isExistMesh()) 
        {
            shader.setUniformMatrix("modelMatrix", child->getTransformation());
            child->getMesh().draw();
        }
    });
}
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

```
E0413   no suitable conversion function from "lambda []void (Graphics::SceneGraph::Node *child)->void" to "GLvoid (*)(Graphics::SceneGraph::Node *child)"
```

Что можно придумать, чтобы исправить это?

Comment: Использовать вместо `GLvoid(*callback)(Node* child)` - `function<GLvoid(Node*)>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
GLvoid Graphics::SceneGraph::Node::childrenForEach(GLvoid(*callback)(Node* child)) noexcept
{
    Node* iterator = mChild;
    while (iterator) 
    {
        callback(iterator);
        iterator = iterator->mNextNode;
    }
}
```

В эту функцию нельзя передавать лямбды, сюда нужно передавать свободную функцию или статическу функцию.

Передать лямбдю можно только в том случае, когда она может быть преобразована в свободную функцию, а такое возможно только когда она не захватывает переменные из вне.

Самый лучшим вариантом, будет изменить сигнатуру функции `childrenForEach` на:

```
GLvoid Graphics::SceneGraph::Node::childrenForEach(std::function<GLvoid(Node *)> callback)) noexcept
{
    Node* iterator = mChild;
    while (iterator) 
    {
        callback(iterator);
        iterator = iterator->mNextNode;
    }
}
```

Если это невозможно, то отказаться от захвата переменных в лямбду и искать другие пути для доступа к `shader`:

```
mRootNode->childrenForEach([](Node* child)
{
    if (child->isExistMesh()) 
    {
        //shader.setUniformMatrix("modelMatrix", child->getTransformation());
        child->getMesh().draw();
    }
});
```

Возможно вообще отказаться от использования функции `childrenForEach` и самому организовать обход элементов.

Дополнено:
По поводу других способов доступа к переменной: без описания типа `Graphics::SceneGraph::Node` сложно что-то сказать, но скорее всего там есть методы для прохода по всем дочерним элементам без колбек функций.
Другим способом будет сделать переменную `shader` но я бы не назвал это хорошим решением. Дайте ссылку где почитать про `Graphics::SceneGraph::Node` и тогда будет проще помочь.

Comment: "и искать другие пути для доступа к shader" - например?

Comment: @QuickDzen дополнил ответ

Comment: https://github.com/VladimirBalun/RacingWorld/blob/develop/ClientSide/Sources/Graphics/SceneGraph/Node.hpp

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите иметь возможность передавать лямбды с захватом, то придется либо делать `childrenForEach` шаблонной

```
template <typename F>
GLvoid Graphics::SceneGraph::Node::childrenForEach(F callback) noexcept
{
  ...
}
```

(и соответствующим образом подправить объявление в классе).

Либо использовать `std::function`

```
GLvoid Graphics::SceneGraph::Node::childrenForEach(std::function<GLvoid(Node*)>) noexcept
{
  ...
}
```

Для такой небольшой функции лучше подойдет как раз первый вариант, ибо он не влечет подавления оптимизаций и накладных расходов на каждый вызов, связанных с `std::function`.

Однако еще лучшим вариантом будет полное отвязывание логики итерирования от вашего класса. В идеале: реализация логики итерирования через класс итератора по списку, а цикл ваш тогда будет записываться через обычный `std::for_each`, в который вы сможете передавать что угодно в качестве функтора.